# Help with PayPal

Tags: paypal

I've just opened a PayPal account and have been trying to add money to my balance or transfer money from my bank to my PayPal account (I haven't got a card yet so I figured I can only do it through PayPal balance) Nothing works!! 
I did link it to my bank, which is a "checking" type of bank, I don't know if it's relevant and clicking transfer funds only means taking money from my PayPal and add it to my bank, instead of vice versa.
I also don't know if it's because my balance is currently 0 so they don't offer the feature? I don't know what to do, been trying for hours. It's frustrating because in all the articles and videos I found, they all have the very features I cannot find ("add money" and "transfer money"). 
Please help, thank you so much.

Comment: Which country are you in?

Comment: Did you contact Paypal support?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. When you make a payment via PayPal, PayPal will *automatically* deduct it from your linked bank account (or credit/debit card, if you've connected those) as needed in a business day or two. If you've multiple payment methods it'll even ask you which one to deduct from.

Comment: Has you confirmed the checking account with PayPal?  IIRC, they use micropayments to verify that you have access to paypal and the account you're linking.

Comment: There are big differences between countries in what features are available or not, so it is indeed important that you tell us what country you are in.

Comment: @ceejayoz This is the correct answer, you should post it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Also, Paypal recently discontinued the "holding a balance with Paypal" thing unless you sign up for their Paypal card account.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's probably not the answer you want to hear, but I really suggest contacting their support. There's always a bit of a wait time but they've always been very helpful to me.